# ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is connecting

Tags: asp.net, exception, odbc, idatareader

I have an ASP.NET web page. It makes use of 4 `BackgroundWorkers`. Each bw retrieves some data from a database.

The code for connecting to the database is:

```
if (dbConnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
{
    dbConnection.Open();
}    
DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(sqlQuery, dbConnection);
cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
IDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
dt.Load(dataReader);
dataReader.Close();
dataReader.Dispose();
```

In the constructor, `this.dbConnection = new OdbcConnection(networkdetails);`

Each bw makes use of the above code snippet to query the database and retrieve the values. The code works perfectly fine sometimes. Other times it throws the exception given above.

Any help as to what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you need 4 background workers on a page? Its not a normal practice in asp.net and can cause a lot of problems.

Comment: You can use  if (Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
Connection.Open(); sometimes connection state may cause the problem.Try like this.

Comment: What is the exception,you are getting it?

Comment: @nunespascal Each query takes substantially long to run. So its definitly better to have 4 concurrent threads to run parallely right? It will cut down on the execution time.

Comment: @MahaSwetha The exception thrown is: ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is connecting.

Comment: @Soul,since stste is connecting,it is not being opened as per your code.Try the way I said above and let me know.

Comment: @MahaSwetha I tried the way you suggested. A bigger problem has cropped up now, since the application is in a multi-threaded environment. Two or more threads satisfy the `if` statement and try to open the connection. Since the connection is already opened by atleast one of these threads, it throws an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try to handle the exception and then close the connection.

For this, write your code in 'Try' block, catch the exception in 'Catch' block and close the connection in 'Finally' block.

```
try{
      // Your code
}
catch
{
      // Catch exception
}
Finally
{
      // Close the connection
      dbConnection.Close();
}
```